# Corned beef scaling

Tags: cooking-time

Say I have a recipe for a 4.4 pound flat cut corned beef for 300F for two hours in a roaster pan. I want to add another very similar but SLIGHTLY thicker 4.7 pounder which fits into the same pan with plenty of space separation. If keeping the 300F temp level, what, if any adjustment, do I need to make.

Comment: To the cooking time

Comment: The fact that they are in the same pan is not significant if they are separated. You can cook the the same as if they were in separate pans and remove the smaller one a bit early.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion... Are you cooking one slightly larger piece of meat, or two pieces (as @JamesMcLeod suggests)?

Comment: How could one cook a single piece of meat “with plenty of space separation?”